# How to perform different task on the basis of elements present in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var fruitsVeg = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "tomato", "onion"];
```

if (fruitsVeg contains "tomato" or "onion" or "tomato and onion") then

```
alert("your array has only vegetables");
```

if (fruitsVeg contains "apple" or "orange" or "banana" or "apple and orange" or "apple and banana" or "orange and banana") then

```
alert("your array has only fruits");
```

if (fruitsVeg contains any element(s) from fruits only and from vegetables only i.e. `var fruitsVeg = ["apple", "orange", "tomato", "onion"];` ) then

```
alert("your array has both fruits and vegetables");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Readability-first example:** Use `indexOf()` to create your conditions, like for example:

```js
var fruitsVeg = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "tomato", "onion"];
var isVege = fruitsVeg.indexOf("tomato") > - 1 || fruitsVeg.indexOf("onion") > -1
var isFruit = fruitsVeg.indexOf("orange") > - 1 || fruitsVeg.indexOf("apple") > -1 || fruitsVeg.indexOf("banana") > -1;

if(isVege && isFruit)
    console.log("your array has both fruits and vegetables");
else if (isVege)
    console.log("your array has only vegetables");
else if (isFruit)
    console.log("your array has only fruits");
```

**Performance-first example:** Assign `bool` values in single loop through all the items and `break` out of it if `fruitsVeg` contains both types of plants:

```js
var fruitsVeg = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "tomato", "onion"];
var isVege    = false;
var isFruit   = false;

function fruit(item) {
    return item === "apple" || item === "banana" || item === "orange"; 
} 

function vege(item) {
    return item === "tomato" || item === "onion";
}

for(var i = 0; i < fruitsVeg.length; i++) {
    var item = fruitsVeg[i];
    if(isVege && isFruit) {
        console.log("Both.");
        break;
    } else if (vege(item)) {
        isVege = true;
    } else if (fruit(item)) {
        isFruit = true;
    }
}

if( !(isVege && isFruit) ) {
    if(isVege) 
        console.log("Vege");
    else if(isFruit)
        console.log("Fruit");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Trivial Version

```js
var alert = console.log.bind(console) // for demo purposes

var fruitsVeg = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "tomato", "onion"];

var hasFruits = fruitsVeg.includes("tomato") || fruitsVeg.includes("onion")
var hasVeges = fruitsVeg.includes("apple") || fruitsVeg.includes("orange") || fruitsVeg.includes("banana")

if (hasFruits && hasVeges) alert("both fruits and vegetables")
else if (hasFruits) alert("only fruits")
else alert("only vegetables")
```

---

Edit: I figured I would take a shot at a more performant example, too, because why not!

### Fast Version

```js
var alert = console.log.bind(console) // for demo purposes

var fruitsVeg = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "tomato", "onion"];

var hasFruits = false,
    hasVeges = false

if (fruitsVeg.some(function(e) {
    if (/^(tomato|onion)$/.test(e)) hasVeges = true
    else if (/^(apple|orange|banana)$/.test(e)) hasFruits = true
    return hasFruits && hasVeges
})) {
  alert('both fruits and vegetables')
} else {
  alert(hasFruits ? 'only fruits' : 'only vegetables')
}
```